# Is it possible to list all the tables of a database with a SQL statement?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am new here so I am phasing some problems in database, please help me.

My question: Is it possible to list all the tables of a database with a SQL statement?

Answer (score 1):

The names of the tables in a MySQL database are stored in the `information_schema` database. You can issue the following query against it:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '[yourDatabaseHere]';
```

Comment: $set1 = mysql_query("SELECT * TABLE_NAME FROM TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'demopss'");

$dbs1 = array(); I am using this code is this correct plese help me on this issue 
while($db1 = mysql_fetch_row($set1))
   $dbs1[] = $db1[0];
echo implode('<br/>', $dbs1);

Comment: +1 for the only cross-platform solution posted so far.  `information_schema` can be a goldmine.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue this command to get all databases:

`show databases;`

And this command for all tables:

`show tables;`

Answer (score 0):

Well in MySQL , once you select a database the query would be

`show tables` and that returns the name of all the tables.

Is this what you wanted ?

From php you can do a `mysql_query` with the sql statement being `show tables`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SHOW TABLES;`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html